# Remove Object in Map from Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity `Mealplan`, where each `weekday (enum)` contains a `meal`. This is realised with a map and a Many-to-Many relation like this:

```
@Entity
public class Mealplan {

  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @ManyToMany
  @SortNatural
  private Map<Weekday, Meal> mealsPerWeek;

(...)

}
```

This means, in my database the mealsPerWeek property is stored in an extra table. "mealplan_meals_per_week". This table contains the mealplan_id, the meal_per_week_id (mealID) and the weekday_id.

Now, if I remove a `Mealplan`, everything gets deleted as I am expecting it. But if I want to delete a `Meal`, following SQL error occurs:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FKPIBLWWQG1HR2D5W7BGORA9XBB: PUBLIC.ESSENSPLAN_ESSEN_PRO_WOCHE FOREIGN KEY(ESSEN_PRO_WOCHE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ESSEN(ID) (1)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKPIBLWWQG1HR2D5W7BGORA9XBB: PUBLIC.ESSENSPLAN_ESSEN_PRO_WOCHE FOREIGN KEY(ESSEN_PRO_WOCHE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ESSEN(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from essen where id=? [23503-200]
```

I am expecting that If I delete a Meal, the line in mealplan gets deleted but everything else stays the same.

Note: CasdadeType.REMOVE is not an option, because it deletes every Mealplan too, where the meal i want to remove is in it.

```
@Entity
public class Essen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Because meal has a reference in mapping table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mealplan_meals_per_week` table there is a reference of `Meal` in `meal_per_week_id` column. So where you are trying to delete `Meal` without cascade reference can't be resolved.

So first delete the references of `Meal` in `mealplan_meals_per_week` table and then delete `Meal`.

Since you are not using Entity for `mealplan_meals_per_week`, you can use native SQL to define query using nativeQuery.

```
@Query(
  value = "DELETE FROM mealplan_meals_per_week m WHERE m.meal_per_week_id= ?1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByMealId(Interger mealId);
```

Comment: is there something like an JPA Repository method, or will it be via a custom sql command?

Comment: Since you are not using Entity for `mealplan_meals_per_week` and don't use cascading then custom sql is only option

Comment: That was it. perfect. I marked it as correct answer. I have one simple question tough: what does the "m" mean in the Query? Could you give me the keyword so I can look it up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Aliasing table name https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp